# Images In SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

Is it better to save a image path as (varchar) in a database or save it as blob/varbinary. The image will appear on front end and I will be using asp classic to implement that.

Comment: Each option has pros and cons, which renders the question too broad. I suggest you research the subject and post more specific questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking I find that it is easier to save the image path in the database.  This makes the database more portable and I find that it is easier to control access to the data.

There is a discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay) that gets further in depth.  They come to the same conclusion that I do.  **File paths are *generally* better.**

Comment: Don't agree, but then again the question is [primary opinion based](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and not a good fit for this site so this will happen.